# I can't get my generated App Access Token to work

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm trying to use my generated App Access Token with requests to the Graph API, but for some unknown reason it simply will not work.  I always get the dreaded `Invalid OAuth access token signature` error.

Now, let me clarify: I'm pretty sure I know what I'm doing.  I *did* get it to work with a *different* FB app.  I used the `/oauth/access_token` call to generate the App Access Token, and I can use that Token successfully in further graph calls for that FB app.

But when I try it for my *new* FB application, it fails.  This is the Rails snippet:

```
app_access_token = URI.escape(ENV["FACEBOOK_APP_ACCESS_TOKEN"])
url = "https://graph.facebook.com/debug_token?input_token=#{user_access_token}&access_token=#{app_access_token}"
response = HTTParty.get(url)
```

I've also tried not-encoding the token; as expected, it doesn't work (and shouldn't).

I've double- and triple-checked my App ID and App Secret, and re-ran the generation (via curl), and I think it's all correct and copy/pasted without error.  The only possibly-notable difference between the generated token of my old app and that of my new one is that the latter has a hyphen in it.  Is that relevant?

I am currently working around this by using `<App ID>|<App Secret>` in place of the generated token, but I'd really like to get back to doing it the right way.

Comment: Have you checked your token via https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/ ?

Comment: That is a useful page to know, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Argh!  It turns out that I had a few extra characters that somehow got attached to the end of my generated token!

I don't know how those got there, but that was the problem.  Just dumb old human error.

**EDIT:** Oh my god, every Facebook developer should know this page:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/accesstoken/
Why isn't that linked from the docs about the access token?  It would have saved me so much time and probably prevented my mistake!